# Split React website in separate modules and load as npm dependency in one package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I am working on a react website which has few separate sections for ex. contact management, message management, etc. All these sections are quite big. The navigation to these sections is controlled from a single dashboard. As we have separate teams working on each team sections, we want to deconstruct the app into individual modules which will contain each part of the website. I haven't done this before, but I want to load these modules as npm dependency into the main app which will handle navigation between each module. I am trying to this to segregate the work and anyone introducing any changes that might break other sections. Sorry for being a bit vague, but your help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily done.

Each individual npm package (for example `module1`) will depend on `react` (but not `react-dom`), and contain a number of files `export`ing React components.

Then the main dashboard would list each package under `dependencies` (as well as `react-dom` and `react`) and can `import` and render the components, for example `import {ContactManager} from 'module1'`.

Each module can in turn `import` common stuff from the dashboard or a separate common package.